# Assign all Post in Wp to a specific Category

Tags: plugins, database

I Cleared off all data in wordpress wp_postmeta, wp_terms, wp_term_relationship, wp_term_taxonomy.

I have post content of 50k. Is there any way I can assign all the 50 posts to a new Category I just created, I will recommend using.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find out the ID of the category that you want to assign. You'll see it in the URL when editing the category (URL will be something like `?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=3&post_type=post`, here **3** is the ID)
2. Assuming that the ID is 3, you can now run this query in your database (eg via PHPMyAdmin)

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships
   (object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
   (  
      SELECT DISTINCT ID, 3
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
   );
   ```

If you use a different prefix than `wp_`, be sure to change it. Also change the **3** to the ID you want.

Comment: Why do you use **LIKE** instead **=**  here: `post_type LIKE 'post'`, `post_status LIKE 'publish'`?

Comment: @nmr I thought `LIKE` is a cleaner way to compare strings. But [= seems to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515039/use-or-like-to-compare-strings-in-sql) and since I'm not using wildcards, I changed it to `=`, good catch